# Mysql работа с датой

Tags: mysql, дата

Как в данной ситуации будет правильнее хранить дату.Есть таблица праздников,которая хранит в себе праздники для нескольких стран.Мне нужно хранить дату начала и конца праздника,чтобы потом вычислять длительность праздника.Вопрос в том,если я внесу праздник на данный момент в 2016 году,как в 2017 система поймет что наступил этот день? Обновлять год у всех праздников на текущий или просто хранить месяц и день каждого праздника без года.

Comment: Тут есть еще один момент. Праздники в следующем году по различным причинам могут быть несколько иными... Т.е. как минимум нужен еще и интервал действия

Comment: Не совсем понял о каком интервале речь!

Comment: Ну кажем возьмем день Великой Октябрьской революции. С 1918г до 1991г отмечался 7 и 8 ноября. в 1992г 8 ноября стал рабочим днем.  1995 он (7-е) стал днем воинской славы, 1996 - день согласия и примирения. С 2005 года 7 ноября перестал быть праздником. Таким образом если мы хотим хранить одной записью, то для 8 ноября надо указать интервал действия с 1918 по 1991. Я бы хранил в виде дат на какой нибудь базовый год, так разницу проще вычислять. Но мне кажется могут быть еще грабли в феврале с високосными годами. И вполне могут быть праздники, по дням недели, типа "второй понедельник марта"

Comment: А сам праздник как лучше хранить? Строкой формата MM-DD и приклеивать потом текущий год?

Comment: А вы как хотите что бы февраль себя вел. Например праздник  27 февраля по 2 марта. он должен быть длиннее на день в високосных или нет. А если просто 29 февраля. А если приклеить 02-29 к 2017 году, то получим недопустимую дату, ошибку выполнения или NULL ...

Comment: Идея в том чтобы внести в систему праздники,и дальше если сотрудник отсутсвует на работе в данный день,чтобы система распознавала отсутствие как уважительное.

Comment: Тогда вы неправильно назвали эту сущность, в бухгалтерии это называется "производственный календарь" и включает не только сами праздники, но и перенесенные выходные/рабочие дни. 20 февраля суббота была рабочей, сегодня 7 марта - выходной. Производственный календарь в России принимается постановлениями правительства каждый год... каждый год он разный

Comment: Ну в моем случае будет все немного проще,будем администратор который сам будет отмечать отсутствие или присутствие сотрудника,по тем праздникам которые введены в систему самим админом то есть дефолтные

Comment: ну я бы все таки сделал наверно тупо дублирование записей на каждый год. Админ все равно каждый год должен смотреть распоряжения правительства и менять календарь

Comment: То есть каждый год переписывать заново праздники всех необходимых стран?

Comment: А почему нет. Вам что бы сотрудника проверить идеально было бы не брать весь календарь а тупо искать дата-сотрудника between или вообще = дата-календаря. При join таблиц сборка год-день или коррекция даты дорого обойдется. хотя можно взять только дату без года у сотрудника и жестко поискать ее в календаре. И кстати, а зачем вам все страны ?

Comment: Не все,на данный момент только для 4-ех стран

Answer (score 1):

Проблема обширная.

- Повторяемость: для религиозных праздников характерна привязка к дню недели, а возможно к лунному календарю.
- Регламентируемость. Правительство утверждает и отменяет праздники. В комментариях вам на это указали.

Боюсь без ручной корректировки каждый год не обойтись. Я бы сделал возможность копирования данных за год для последующей модерации.

**UPDATED**:
Возможно для вашей задачи вам будет достаточно знать "производственный календарь", который утверждается властями на следующий год. Хранить его можно просто как список нерабочих дней, по одной записи на день. В вашем случае ещё с атрибутом страны.

Полезные ссылки по теме:

- [Calendar Recurring/Repeating Events - Best Storage Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183630/calendar-recurring-repeating-events-best-storage-method)
- [Производственный календарь на 2016 год](http://www.consultant.ru/law/ref/calendar/proizvodstvennye/)
- [Пример подсчета рабочих дней в производственном календаре](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b190/6)